# How to rotate an Image using Itex7 and C#?

Tags: pdf, .net-core, itext7

I am using the C#SDK for [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en) . As a simple test I'm creating a PDF with an Image in it. What I want to do is to rotate this Image in the PDF. This is the code I'm using

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("./test.pdf", new WriterProperties().SetPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0));
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdfDocument.SetTagged();
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create("google-logo.png")).SetRotationAngle(90).SetAutoScale(true);
document.Add(image);
document.Close();
```

However, in the generated file, the Image shows like this
[image]

So how can I rotate the Image by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of `Image#SetRotationAngle` says that the value must be passed in radians, not in angles.

So just replacing `image.SetRotationAngle(90)` with `image.SetRotationAngle(Math.PI / 2)` should do the trick